# How do I run all tests in a directory without crashes?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

When I do `goapp test ./..` in my app directory, I get spurious failures from the dev_appserver.py script. Example:

```
INFO     2014-06-14 15:09:43,457 devappserver2.py:706] Skipping SDK update check.
WARNING  2014-06-14 15:09:43,457 devappserver2.py:722] DEFAULT_VERSION_HOSTNAME will not be set correctly with --port=0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 82, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 78, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 943, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 936, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 749, in start
    request_data, storage_path, options, configuration)
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 848, in _create_api_server
    default_gcs_bucket_name=options.default_gcs_bucket_name)
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/api_server.py", line 359, in setup_stubs
    auto_id_policy=datastore_auto_id_policy)
  File "/home/travis/go_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_sqlite_stub.py", line 629, in __init__
    (self.__datastore_file, e))
google.appengine.runtime.apiproxy_errors.ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 3 Data in /tmp/appengine.testapp.travis/datastore.db is corrupt or a different version. Try running with the --clear_datastore flag.
OperationalError('database schema has changed',)
```

Note that even though this particular example is runing on Travis CI; I *do* get the same failures when running locally.

If I run individual tests one at a time, they all pass just fine.

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests? `--clear_datastore`

Comment: --clear_datastore is not a flag that goapp understands, it seems to be a flag for dev_appserver.py, to which I have no access.

Comment: also, the particular way it fails varies: it's not always this particular error. It strongly smells of race condition between unit tests.